# Error occurred in deployment step 'Add Solution': Sandboxed code execution request failed (but no implementation at all)

Tags: visual-studio, sandbox-solution

I realize of course that there is [another question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/7640/error-occurred-in-deployment-step-add-solution-sandboxed-code-execution-reque) with the same title, and mine is a very similar question, but with a slightly different issue, I think:

I have created an empty feature with an event receiver.  I uncommented the `FeatureActivated` and `FeaturedDeactivating` methods, but they have no implementation.

When I press F5 to deploy from SharePoint 2010, it builds, but then fails with the error as it appears in the title.

I couldn't find much useful in ULS, and there's nothing in the event log.  What gives?

Comment: Is there anything else being deployed in the Feature?

Comment: @JamesLove nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regardless of what code, or lack thereof, is contained in the solutuion SharePoint will still execute the user/sandobexed soultion inside the sandbox, i.e. it is run but the User Code Service.

I'd take a look at the setup of the User Code Serivce and verify that it is correct, this blog posting may help: http://bramnuyts.wordpress.com/2011/05/17/sandboxed-code-execution-request-failed/

I've also encoutered problems deploying sandboxed solutions from visual studio where they just would not work until they had be been deployed and activated manually once.

Comment: I changed the setting as suggested, and it appears to have worked.  However, my farm is a standalone installation (and a fresh installation), so why would this work now and now before?